# Whats the difference between cell phone and data radiation

Tags: wi-fi, mobile-data

Is cell phone and data/WiFi/LTE radiation the same thing?  Or are they entirely different technologies?

Are any of them dangerous? I ask because i use my phone a lot at night in bed and i look at my phone really close to my face when I'm lying down. I don't call but use LTE and WiFi mostly and I'm worried that it might be dangerous.

Comment: All I can really say definitively is that it is indeed the same thing. There's lots of information about the potential hazards of cell radiation, with no clear conclusion. I'm no doctor, but the general consensus seems to be that it's safe enough to keep near your head for prolonged periods of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are all electromagnetic waves with different wavelengths. There had been no scientific evidence that they're dangerous in the power level used in common appliances, and many researches shows no evidence of danger in the short term studies, however many countries adopts the precautionary approach and advises people to minimize exposure just in case since long term study and study in  children has not been conclusive yet (these kind of studies takes a very long time since they follow their subjects for decades), although preliminary results suggests that long term effect may also be of no danger.

You're probably more likely to be killed in a car accident then getting a cancer due to mobile phone radiation.